# Key Value array in C# put into parameter

Tags: c#, php, arrays

Coming from PHP, I have never written C# before and I have encountered something like this in C#:

```
public string rule(string playerId, string action, params string[] optionalData){
...
}
```

and in PHP it is like this

```
public function rule($playerId, $action, $optionalData=array()){
...
}
```

In PHP I simply fill out the parameter for the $optionalData like this...

```
myVar->rule("123", "myAction", array('url'=>'review.com');
```

However in C# I am not sure how to fill the optionalData (params string[] optionalData) parameter as it is a key value parameter (like in the PHP example). My question is how do I create a key value array like the PHP that I created in my example and put into the parameter?

```
CoolClass cc = new CoolClass();
cc.rule("123", "myAction", ???);
```

I was searching google and was looking at dictionary and hashmaps etc but I am guessing it is an overkill or it does not work..

Many thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries appear to be the right tool for your job - atleast based on what I see here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you were looking at dictionaries, you were definitely looking at the right facility.

If `rule()` in C# is in your own code, may I recommend changing the signature to:

```
public string rule(string playerId, string action, IDictionary<string, string> optionalData = new Dictionary<string, string>()){
...
}
```

What this allows you to do:

- Operate on the values in `optionalData` the way that other C# programmers will expect.
- The `= new Dictionary<string, string>()` part of the suggested method signature make the parameter truly optional. It will not be necessary when calling the method.
- You can use `IDictionary<T>` methods to work with the data. Some syntax you should be somewhat familiar with (consider accessing by key `optionalData["someString"]`.)

However, if `rule()` is not in your code, you would leave out the optionalData by simply omitting parameters. Examples of valid calls of the original C# method in your question:

- `rule("Bob", "load")`
- `rule("Bob", "load", "url", "www.example.com")` (In this case, `optionalData[0].Equals("url", StringComparisonOptions.Ordinal)` and `optionalData[1].Equals("www.example.com", StringComparisonOptions.Ordinal)` is true.

One thing to consider about the original method - keep in mind that `rule("Bob", "load", 'url")` is a valid call, and you would need to have a run-time check to make sure you had the right number of parameters. Another plus to using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You may even consider writing an adapter method to the original `rule()`, if you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,string[]>
```

or something like:

```
Dictionary<int, string[]>
```

I believe dictionary will work in your case.

Comment: This is what I wrote and I am getting errors 'The best overloaded method match for 'ApplicationName.CoolClass.rule(string, string, params string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: This is my code:  Dictionary<string, string[]> test = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

Comment: string[] names = new string[] {"review"};

Comment: test.Add("url",names);

Comment: The first part in Dictionary `string` or `int` in our case is the Key - you should be passing PlayerID where you put Url, and in the array pass "url" in the first index of the string array and names in the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary <key_datatype, value_datatype>` .

**Example:**

Your method definition here :

```
public string rule(string playerId, string action, Dictionary<string, string> optionalData){
...
}
```

Method call:

```
Dictionary<string, string> optionalData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
optionalData.Add("url", "review.com");

cc.rule("123", "myAction", optionalData);
```

Or

**you can use `DynamoObject` to make it more easier to write:**

```
    dynamic optionalData = new ExpandoObject();

//The token after the dynamoObject period will be the key to the assigned value.
    optionalData.url = "review.com";

    cc.rule("123", "myAction", optionalData);
```

Your method can get the key-value pairs like this:

```
public string rule(string playerId, string action, dynamic optionalData)
{
...

            foreach (var pair in (IDictionary<string, object>)optionalData)
            {
                if (group.Key == "url")
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
                }
                else if (group.Key == "post")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
                }
            }
 }
```